# Abandoning a reinstatement of F1 and left the US

Tags: usa, f1-visas

I applied for the reinstatement of an F1 visa within the approved period.

I left the US while my application was being processed. Does this mean that I can not reenter the US under another type of visa?

Comment: You can apply for a visa. If you're approved you can enter. However entry into the USA is ultimately determined by the immigration officer at the port of entry. Once you left the USA, the application for reinstatement was deemed abandoned.

Comment: I presume you are asking about a student visa, so I removed the tag about racing.